# Компиляция PHP под Windows

Tags: компилятор, windows, php

Привет! Подскажите хороший компилятор под Windows для PHP.

P.S еще один вопрос: как можно зашифровать PHP-проект? Т.е его исходники, как это делают host-cms.

Comment: вы ведь конечно же знаете, что php - интерпретируемый язык?

Comment: Это не мешает написать прогу, которая скомпилит его в байт-код или что-то подобное, после чего он перестанет работать везде, кроме мест, где стоит ДРУГАЯ прога. =)

Comment: @knes я не говорю, что компиляция php невозможна. Я говорю о том, что ТСа скорее всего интересует не компиляция php во что-то ещё, а просто возможность писать на php под Windows. Хотя, могу и ошибаться

Comment: @DreamChild @knes мне не нужно компилировать его в программу, нужно скомпилировать его под windows, т.к HipHop'a под винду нет.

Comment: @DreamChild http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться стеком wamp (там сразу apache,mysql и php), есть сборки с очень удобной панелью управления.

Насчёт зашифровать советую сначала ознакомиться со статейкой - [Обфускация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) - и выбрать что больше подходит.

Comment: @Deadik Именно об обфускации и я говорил, что посоветуете?

Comment: @Lektor, так обфускация и компиляция это разное:-) Вопрос перефразируйте.

Answer (score 0):

NuSphere PhpExpress Вполне с этой задачей справляется.
Я, правда, сильно сомневаюсь, что у вас настолько уникальный проект, что его захотят стянуть. В этом случае не спасет даже такое преобразование.

P.S. Обычно после следует комментарий "где бы достать кряк к этой проге", либо "а бесплатного ничего нет?"

Answer (score 0):

DevelStudio, хорошая вещь, с хорошей [поддержкой](http://community.develstudio.ru/). И это не только компилятор, а целая среда разработки! Очень удобно, не нужно писать графический интерфейс ручками.